# Cross sites links are resolving as a context site link (Sitecore 9 Update 2)

Tags: multisite, link-manager

I am having an issue in Sitecore 9.0.2 that cross sites links are not resolving properly. The link is resolved as a context site link and when I click on that link it gives me 404 so anyone has any idea on this?

I have two sites -

1. corporate
2. corporate.jp.local

When I linked any item(Home/test/test1) of Site 1(corporate) in Site 2(corporate.jp.local). It generates the URL with the second site.

Example: `corporate.jp.local/test/test1`

Already tried below solutions but they've not worked:

- [Cross-site links not resolving correctly in RTE fields on multi-site environment](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3408/cross-site-links-not-resolving-correctly-in-rte-fields-on-multi-site-environment)
- [Sitecore multisite cross links not resolved with proper hostname](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/sitecore-multisite-cross-links-not-resolved-with-proper-hostname)

### Sitedefinition structure

```
<site name="japan" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            hostName="corporate.jp.local"
            targetHostName="corporate.jp.local"
            language="ja-JP"
            enableFallback="true"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/jp"
            startItem="/Home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="10MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false" />


    <site name="English" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
      hostName="corporate"
      targetHostName="corporate"
      language="en"
      virtualFolder="/"
      physicalFolder="/"
      rootPath="/sitecore/content/en"
      startItem="/home"
      database="web"
      domain="extranet"
      allowDebug="true"
      cacheHtml="true"
      htmlCacheSize="100MB"
      enablePreview="true"
      enableWebEdit="true"
      enableDebugger="true"
      disableClientData="false" />
```

### Tree structure

#### japan

- Home

  - test

    - test1

#### test

- Home

  - test

    - test1

Comment: Do you have alwaysIncludeServerUrl set to "true" in your LinkManager configurations?

Comment: Yes, It is set to true

Comment: do you have `targetHostName` in your site definitions?

Comment: Yes, targetHostName it there.

Comment: Can you include your sites definition and tree structure in your question?

Comment: @marek Updated ticket

Comment: @RavindraS.Rathore i do not see  language="en" or  language="jp" node in above config setting. Could you try adding that?

Comment: Try to add the hostName attribute also as from what i know, Sitecore does some check based on the hostName and targetHostName

Comment: @MrunalDaftari I tried with adding language="en" but still the result is same

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Also added the hostName but nothing worked

Comment: I should very much like to see what you did with the SiteResolving setting

Comment: @MarkCassidy SiteResolving setting is true and i also tried with using custom linkprovider and checked that this setting is true and it coming as true in customprovider

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your Sitecore content tree with those nodes? Do both the nodes `"/sitecore/content/jp"` and `"/sitecore/content/en"` exist?

Comment: @DanSinclair Yes both nodes are exist

Comment: If I were you, the next step I'd try would be to decompile the default `LinkManager`/`LinkProvider` and patch it in with config so I could step through the code and see what it's doing. My guess is that it's resolving the wrong site in the `<sites>` section, but without seeing your tree and tracing the request, I can't say why exactly.